# Unit Testing async method causes error

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await

Here is the test code.

```
[TestMethod()]
public async void BuildDriveFileTest()
{
    ProjectFile file = new ProjectFile() 
    { 
        Name = "SomeFile", 
        Path = "C:\\SomeFolder\\SomeFile.txt", 
        RelativePath = "SomeFolder"
    };
    Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File driveFile = await GoogleDriveConverter.BuildDriveFile(file, "Repository1");
    Assert.AreNotEqual(driveFile.Title, "SomeFile.txt");
    Assert.AreNotEqual(driveFile.MimeType, "application/unknown");
    Assert.AreNotEqual(driveFile.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "ElementType").Value, "ProjectFile");
    Assert.AreNotEqual(driveFile.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "ParentIdentifier").Value, GoogleDriveConverter.ComputeHashString("Repository1\\SomeFolder"));
    Assert.AreNotEqual(driveFile.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "FileIdentifier").Value, GoogleDriveConverter.ComputeHashString("Repository1\\SomeFolder\\SomeFile.txt"));
    Assert.AreNotEqual(driveFile.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "IsLocalRoot").Value, "False");
}
```

I also tried changing method signature

```
[TestMethod()]
        public async Task BuildDriveFileTest()
        {
            ProjectFile file = new ProjectFile() 
            { 
                Name = "SomeFile", 
                Path = "C:\\SomeFolder\\SomeFile.txt", 
                RelativePath = "SomeFolder"
            };
            Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File driveFile = await GoogleDriveConverter.BuildDriveFile(file, "Repository1");
            Assert.AreNotEqual(driveFile.Title, "SomeFile.txt");
            Assert.AreNotEqual(driveFile.MimeType, "application/unknown");
            Assert.AreNotEqual(driveFile.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "IsFile").Value, "True");
            Assert.AreNotEqual(driveFile.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "ParentIdentifier").Value, GoogleDriveConverter.ComputeHashString("Repository1\\SomeFolder"));
            Assert.AreNotEqual(driveFile.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "FileIdentifier").Value, GoogleDriveConverter.ComputeHashString("Repository1\\SomeFolder\\SomeFile.txt"));
            Assert.AreNotEqual(driveFile.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "IsLocalRoot").Value, "False");
            return;
        }
```

It says "Unexpected error detected".
Output Pane doesn't help either.

> The active Test Run was aborted because the execution process exited unexpectedly. To investigate further, enable local crash dumps either at the machine level or for process vstest.executionengine.x86.exe.

By the way, before you say anything about the unit testing **purposes** I may be doing it wrong, but my purpose of Unit testing is like documentation. I am just doing it in order to clearly see what to expect from which unit.

Comment: That code won't even compile - you're trying to use `await` in a non-async method.

Comment: I was trying Task.Result. In the original version I tried it inside an **async void** and **async Task** test methods.

Comment: And what result did you get in each case? It's very hard to help when we can only see an invalid code example, then get told there are actually 3 attempts, but we don't know whether the result is the same in each case...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes. In those three attempt, every time I get the same "Unexpected Error"

Comment: It sounds like possibly there's a severe bug in the code you're calling which is aborting the process. Odd not to get an exception though....

Comment: The other thing is that there is a question here whether or not you are doing the Test approach/testing correctly. you shouldn't rely on external factors but instead do mock ups and test against that and not the real live sources

Comment: @JonSkeet The exact same code that I use in Test Method is working in the program.

Comment: So have you at least diagnosed *where* it's failing? If you remove all the assertions, does that help? I assume if you don't call `BuildDriveFile` at all, it doesn't crash? Note that the sort of application it is may be relevant here - if `BuildDriveFile` assumes that after an `await` expression, it's on the same thread, that may be true in your app (e.g. WinForms) but not in a unit test environment... Can you come up with a short but *complete* example which reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your unit test framework version should support async/await. You may have to update to latest version. Test method signature has to be like.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task BuildDriveFileTest()
{
    ...
}
```

There is [nice MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818493.aspx) on async unit tests

Comment: Sorry. There was an async in method signature. I was just trying Task.Result instead of awaiting it. I am using Microsoft's own unit testing framework. How an I update it?

Comment: VS 2012 and above supports async unit test, but you have to use "async Task", not "async void".  If you use Task.Result everywhere in your test, you can theoretically use non-async test method signature